# Proving that a set of metric space is dense in $A$ iff there exists a sequence converging to $x\in A$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I'm using the following definition:

A set $M$ of a metric space $(\frak M,\rho)$ is called *dense* in a set $A\subset\frak M$ if $$\forall \varepsilon>0,x\in A\exists y\in M:\rho(x,y)<\varepsilon.\tag1$$

I need to prove that $M$ is dense in $A$ iff 
$$\forall x\in A\exists \{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset M:y_n\rightarrow x,\tag2$$
where $y_n\rightarrow x$ means that the sequence of $y_n$'s converges to $x$.

I want to be as rigorous as possible while proving this.

Here's how I approach this. First, I replace $y_n\rightarrow x$ with definition of limit of a sequence, so I have:
$$\forall x\in A\exists \{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset M:\forall\varepsilon>0\;\exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n>N:\rho(x,y_n)<\varepsilon.\tag3$$
Now I move $\forall \varepsilon>0$ to the left (is it a valid operation here?) to make the statement closer to the form of $(1)$:
$$\forall\varepsilon>0, x\in A\exists \{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset M:\exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n>N:\rho(x,y_n)<\varepsilon.\tag4$$

Now this seems to imply $(1)$, since if there's a subsequence of $y_n$'s, satisfying $\rho(x,y_n)<\varepsilon$, then there indeed exists a single such $y$. So, first half of proof is done.

But I have a hard time proving the converse — that $(1)$ implies $(4)$. It seems I have to move $\forall \varepsilon>0$ somewhere and somehow fold a statement about the sequence, but I don't quite understand how.

Could someone give some hints?

Comment: moving the $\forall$ quantor to the left is always valid. BUT: your statement after this move is: for any $\epsilon$ and $x$ there is a sequence such that from a certain index the sequence is closer to $x$ than $\epsilon$. THIS MEANS: you might have a different sequence for each epsilon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix $\epsilon=\frac{1}{1}$ and find $y$ of your definition of density. define $y_{1}:=y$

fix $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and find $y$ of your definition of density. define $y_{2}:=y$

$\cdots$

fix $\epsilon=\frac{1}{k}$ and find $y$ of your definition of density. define $y_{k}:=y$

$\cdots$

this gives (one example for) your sequence.

CONVERSE:

by sequential definition of density you can find $\left(y_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $x$.

fix $\epsilon>0$. then by choice of the sequence there exists $n_{0}$ such that $\forall n\geq n_{0} : d\left(x,y_{n}\right)<\epsilon$. take $y:=y_{n_{0}}$ and you are done.

Comment: Considering a sequence of $\varepsilon$'s and letting it converge to $0$ was the step which I was failing to guess. Thanks.